# Checking sample rate of Alsamixer used with USB DAC

Tags: sound, alsa, music

I am worried that my Alsamixer downsamples my 24bit/96khz music to 16/41 or just generally degrades sound quality. I have done a test with a .flac and .wav file with alsa and it displayed that it is playing at 8khz which is terrible and unlikely.

( My music player is Clementine and I am runnning Ubuntu 15.04 with newest version of alsa but I doubt this is relevant.)

Is there a way to see the actual sample rate that is being outputted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alsamixer` is an application that allows you to access mixer controls of the hardware.
If there is any resampling, it happens elsewhere.

To see the current settings of a hardware device, look into `/proc/asound/cardX/pcm0p/sub0/hw_params`, with `X` depending on which of your cards you're using.